# Passing by pointer warnings in c

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, pass-by-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(int **asciiSum);

int main(void)
{
     int asciiSum;
     asciiSum = 0;

     int* pointToAsciiSum;
     *pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;

     printf("%d\n",*pointToAsciiSum); //prints 0
     foo(pointToAsciiSum)
     printf("%d\n",*pointToAsciiSum); //prints 2

     return 0;
}
int foo(int** asciiSum)
{
    *asciiSum = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get rid of the warnings?

Warnings:

warning C4047: 'function' : 'int **' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *' //occurs when calling foo

warning C4024: 'foo' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1   //occurs when calling foo

warning C4047: '=' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' //occurs in foo, when assigning 2 to *asciiSum

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: @EOF Your explanation does not apply.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The hell it doesn't: `int* pointToAsciiSum;
     *pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;` uses the pointer (which is an object with automatic storage duration) while it is indeterminate. Come to think if it, it's also a constraint violation, which begs the question where the corresponding compiler warning is.

Comment: `*pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;` --> `pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;`, `foo(pointToAsciiSum)` --> `foo(&pointToAsciiSum);`, `*asciiSum = 2;` --> `**asciiSum = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

```
 int* pointToAsciiSum;
 *pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;
```

should be

```
 int* pointToAsciiSum;
 pointToAsciiSum = &asciiSum;
```

You want to assign to the pointer, not to the `int` to which the (uninitialized) pointers points.

---

```
int foo(int** asciiSum) { 
    *asciiSum = 2;
```

should be

```
int foo(int* pointToAsciiSum) { 
    *pointToAsciiSum = 2;
```

Let's use consistent names. The main problem, though, is that the sub expects a pointer to a pointer, but there's no need to that. You want to change the `int`, so you simply need a pointer to that `int`.

---

All together, without all the extra pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* num_ptr) {
   *num_ptr = 2;
}

int main(void) {
     int num = 0;
     printf("%d\n", num);

     foo(&num);
     printf("%d\n", num);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, why are most tutorials on pointers overly confusing? This format makes a lot more sense, thanks!